# ehcache default settings

Tags: java, ehcache

When using ehcache you configure a set of caches in an XML file (typically). Each cache has a plethora of settings that can be configured, e.g.

- name
- eternal
- overflowToDisk
- maxElementsInMemory
- maxElementsOnDisk

But what happens if you omit some of these parameters. Do they assume sensible default values, and if so, are they documented somewhere?

Comment: Hmmm... two minutes on the ehcache documentation page, and you woulld have this answered.

Comment: @Matt could you post a link to the page that answers this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about version of ehcache you are using but for version 2.10.3, you can find all constant value [here](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10.3/constant-values.html)

You can change the version in URL and navigate through the version you are using.
Generally remains same with different versions until and unless any major change in implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[EHCache document](http://ehcache.org/files/documentation/ehcache-2.5.x-documentation.pdf), keep searching for "default", and you'll find em.